how do i insert multiple rows into supa base from a app state list, on flutterflow
I'm doing a gym app. Under each workout I have different exercise with sets. I have manage to create a row in the workout table. but im trying now to insert multiple rows at the same time into the workout exercises table. In flutterflow, i have a appstate workout, and workoutexercises as a datatype list. my only option is to add item at index but like how can i want all indexes. Thank you
What have you tried so far?
In flutterflow, i have a appstate workout, and workoutexercises as a datatype list. my only option is to add item at index but like how can i want all indexes. Thank you
